# How can I join a row with an arrays inside that row in an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I've got some custom oracle types declared as such:

```
create type S_TYPE as table of VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE TYPE "OBJ_ORDER_ADD" AS object (
  ADD_TYPE NUMBER,
  ADDITION s_type
  -- other fields not represented here for brevity
);

create type ARRAY_ORDER_ADD as table of OBJ_ORDER_ADD;
```

This means that I can create instances of `ARRAY_ORDER_ADD` that look like this:

```
add_type  | addition
---------------------
      10  | ['a', 'b']
      20  | ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I need to create `FUNCTION` that can merge the data contained into a corresponding `order_add` table, where the `addition` column is a `VARCHAR`. After merging the object above into an empty table, I want the table to contain:

```
add_type | addition
-------------------
      10 | 'a'
      10 | 'b'
      20 | 'x'
      20 | 'y'
      20 | 'z'
```

I know that I can use a trivial solution with two nested loops to achieve this, but this solution results in a lot of SQL/PLSQL context switches, and I would like to avoid them.

My ideal goal is to do this using a single `MERGE` query.

Is this possible?

I've tried a few combinations of `SELECT ... FROM TABLE(myRecord)` and tried to somehow make a cartesian product of each record with `TABLE(myRecord.addition)` but I just can't seem to put it together properly.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to add a tag by pressing enter, and somehow that posted the question prematurely. It's complete now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your actual implementation is, but this shows you how to un-nest nested tables in pure SQL.

The WITH clause creates a collection of your sample data, then we use successive `table()` functions to unpack the nested table objects:

```
with cte as (
    select ARRAY_ORDER_ADD(OBJ_ORDER_ADD(10, s_type('a', 'b')) 
                          , OBJ_ORDER_ADD(20, s_type('a', 'b', 'c'))) as nt 
    from dual
    )
select t.add_type
      , x.column_value as s_type_element
 from cte
       , table(cte.nt)  t
       , table(t.addition) x;
```

Comment: I'll try to see if I can adapt that to work with MERGE.

Comment: Works well. I'm apparently now having some other issues that prevent my single merge query to perform better then the current method (10 select-before-update-or-insert). Probably some issues with cardinalities, but that will be a different question if I can't figure it out.